# Command line for() with other conditions doesn't work

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am on Win10 x64 trying to automatize adding several www into Win10 HOSTS file so I do not have to make it manually myself. IF I do it for each www separately one-by-one, it does work, but if I try to use a `for()` loop it does not work and I do not know why (tested that `%%i` has correct values from the array).

So this works:

```
SET HOSTSPATH=%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
SET WWWW=www.somewebsite.com

FIND /C /I "0.0.0.0 %WWW%" %HOSTSPATH%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^0.0.0.0 %WWW%>>%HOSTSPATH%

FIND /C /I "127.0.0.1 %WWW%" %HOSTSPATH%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^127.0.0.1 %WWW%>>%HOSTSPATH%
```

But this one with `for()` not:

```
SET HOSTSPATH=%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
SET WWW=(www.somewebsite1.com www.somewebsite2.com www.somewebsite3.com)

for %%i in %WWW% do (
    FIND /C /I "0.0.0.0 %%i" %HOSTSPATH%
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^0.0.0.0 %%i>>%HOSTSPATH%

    FIND /C /I "127.0.0.1 %%i" %HOSTSPATH%
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^127.0.0.1 %%i>>%HOSTSPATH%
)
```

**UPDATE**

I just played with it a bit more and I think there is some sort of a problem with the `FIND` and/or `IF()` condition(s), cos if I completely remove `FIND` and `IF()` and make it simple add new line without any checking it does work, like this:

```
SET HOSTSPATH=%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
SET WWW=(www.somewebsite1.com www.somewebsite2.com www.somewebsite3.com)

for %%i in %WWW% do (
    ECHO %NEWLINE%^0.0.0.0 %%i>>%HOSTSPATH%
    ECHO %NEWLINE%^127.0.0.1 %%i>>%HOSTSPATH%
)
```

In fact, `FIND` works OK as it reports correctly in case the line already is in the HOSTS files, thus I am almost sure now **it is something with the `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0` section**, but have no clue what.

I just tested that `%ERRORLEVEL%` is reported correctly:

- `0` - line isn't in the file yet
- `1` - line already is in the file

So I really don't know at this point what it can be...

Does anyone know why and how to make it work with both conditions in place?

Comment: In your first `for` example, change `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0` to `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` or enable delayed variable expansion and use `IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0` instead.

Comment: @Compo YES - that works beautifully (changing to `IF ERRORLEVEL 1`): would you be so kind and post this answer as normal one so I can set it as the correct answer, please? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you had attempted the task using `find.exe`, and `findstr.exe` would be a much better tool, I have decided to post an example using that along with the ErrorLevel fix I offered in the comment section:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "HOSTSPATH=%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS"
Set "URLS=www.somewebsite1.com www.somewebsite2.com www.somewebsite3.com"

(For %%G In (%URLS%) Do (Set "HOST=%%G"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        (For %%H In ("!HOST:.=\.!") Do (EndLocal
                %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"^0\.0\.0\.0 %%~H$"^
                 /C:"^127\.0\.0\.1 %%~H$" 1>NUL
                If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo 0.0.0.0 %%G) Else Echo Found %%G 1>CON
            )) 0<"%HOSTSPATH%")) 1>>"%HOSTSPATH%"

Pause
```

I would probably perform the task without using ErrorLevel and instead using success conditionals:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "HOSTSPATH=%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS"
Set "URLS=www.somewebsite1.com www.somewebsite2.com www.somewebsite3.com"

(For %%G In (%URLS%) Do (Set "HOST=%%G"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        (For %%H In ("!HOST:.=\.!") Do (EndLocal
                %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IRC:"^0\.0\.0\.0 %%~H$"^
                 /C:"^127\.0\.0\.1 %%~H$" 1>NUL && (Echo Found %%G 1>CON
                ) || Echo 0.0.0.0 %%G
            )) 0<"%HOSTSPATH%")) 1>>"%HOSTSPATH%"

Pause
```

---

Please note that some characters within your URLs, *(other than the period, `.`, I have already catered for)*, may require special treatment with `findstr.exe` so this solution may not work for all URL's without modification.

*Obviously, this script would need to be run elevated.*